# Cleanup of tags with similar names

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Gilles was nice enough to share a Data.SE query with us [identifying tags with similar names](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/72948/tags-with-similar-names), prime candidates for cleaning up and possibly synonym creation.

I consider the following to be false positives of the query:
<sup>Feel free to comment and disagree.</sup>

- [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) (the OS) and [window](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window) (the GUI concept)
- [http](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/http) and [https](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/https) (if you use the latter, there's usually a good reason)
- [video](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video) and [s-video](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/s-video) (due to how the query finds similar terms)
- [parallels](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parallels) (virtualization software) and [parallel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/parallel) (parallel port or doing two things at the same time)
- [stack](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stack) (programming and debugging) and [stacks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stacks) (file and folder preview in Mac OS X Dock)
- [ibook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ibook) (predecessor to Macbook product line) and [ibooks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ibooks) (Apple's e-books, tag no longer exists)
- [hpux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hpux) / [hp-ux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hp-ux) (only the latter exists)
- [file-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-server) / [fileservers](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fileservers) (only the former exists)
- [zombies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zombies) / [zombie](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zombie) (only the latter exists)
- [list](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/list) / [lists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lists) (both no longer exist)

---

### That leaves the following pairs of candidates for cleanup:

1. [user](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/user) / [users](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/users)
2. [port](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port) / [ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ports)
3. [utf8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf8) / [utf-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)
4. [file-types](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-types) / [filetype](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/filetype)

Any ideas how to handle those?

#### Discuss only one pair of tags per answer please.

Up vote answers to agree, down vote to disagree.

Comment: Is there a reason not to synonymize all of them?

Comment: @soandos I haven't added my thoughts on the other three, but user/users looks pretty useless (we also have `account` without synonym, maybe use that as the synonym target), `port` and `ports` can refer to *networking* and *making software available on a different platform*. So far I only discussed the easy one of these...

Answer (score 3):

[utf8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf8) → [utf-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/utf-8)

Merge and create synonym.

While the former is more popular as a tag, I suggest we go with [the official naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Official_name_and_variants) here:

> Other descriptions that omit the hyphen or replace it with a space, such as "utf8" or "UTF 8", are not accepted as correct by the governing standards.